# Convert string to DateTIme from specific format

Tags: c#

I have the following  string: `Monday, April 20, 2020 at 9:11 AM`,

How can I convert it into `DateTime` object?

What I'm trying:

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(
                      "Monday, April 20, 2020 at 9:11 AM",
                      "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff",
                      System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But as except `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff` not working to this format.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just use the correct specifiers from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings). "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff" is nowhere near the format of your string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/uBnqhz

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact("Monday, April 20, 2020 at 9:20 AM",
                                "dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy 'at' h:m tt",       
                                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: You'd need to use lowercase `h` in the format string so that the 12-hour clock is used (as we have AM/PM here). Uppercase `H` would use a 24-hour clock.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use the following format string: `"dddd, MMMM d, yyyy 'at' h:mm tt"`.

Also, as suggested in the comments, [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact("Monday, April 20, 2020 at 9:11 AM", "dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy 'at' h:mm tt", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en"));
```